# Make it more compact and issue with "Dimension too large"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code that I don't like and generates an error:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red, thick] (0,0) --(6,0);
  \draw[blue, thick] (5,0.2) -- (9,0.2);
  \draw plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0.6) (0.4,1) (1,0.4) (1.6,1.2) (2,1.4) (2.6,0.6) (3.4,1.8) (3.8,1.2) (4.4,1.2)(5,0.8) (5.4,0.4) (6,1) (6.6,2) (7,1.6) (7.4,1) (8.2,0.6) (9,0.4)};
\path[postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark ={between positions 0.6 and 1 step 0.04 with {\fill[blue] circle[radius=0.08cm];}}}] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0.6) (0.4,1) (1,0.4) (1.6,1.2) (2,1.4) (2.6,0.6) (3.4,1.8) (3.8,1.2) (4.4,1.2)(5,0.8) (5.4,0.4) (6,1) (6.6,2) (7,1.6) (7.4,1) (8.2,0.6) (9,0.4)};
    \path[postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings, mark ={between positions 0 and 0.7 step 0.04 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=0.05cm];}}}] plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0.6) (0.4,1) (1,0.4) (1.6,1.2) (2,1.4) (2.6,0.6) (3.4,1.8) (3.8,1.2) (4.4,1.2)(5,0.8) (5.4,0.4) (6,1) (6.6,2) (7,1.6) (7.4,1) (8.2,0.6) (9,0.4)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I don't like is the repetition of the same commands, I am not sure how to streamline the code.

Second issue is that i get an error "Dimension too large" when compiling. I have googled the error but I could not really understand how the suggested solutions fit to my problem.

Any suggestion/pointer is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions. The answer to "how can I avoid repetition" is easy: you can add as many postactions to a path as you want as long as you set the braces right, i.e. instead of

```
`postaction={decorate}, decoration={...}`
```

you need

```
postaction={decorate, decoration={...}}`
```

AFAIK the second question "how can I avoid `dimension too large` errors" does not have a universal answer. The only information that I can offer here is that sometimes scaling the picture helps, and, as shown below, the smooth paths created with `hobby` are much less likely to have the issue. (In fact, so far I had never a `dimension too large` problem with `hobby` paths.) However, the smooth curve also looks somewhat different from what you get with a plain `plot [smooth] coordinates`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red, thick] (0,0) --(6,0);
  \draw[blue, thick] (5,0.2) -- (9,0.2);
  \draw[
    postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark ={between positions 0.6 and 1 step 0.04 with {\fill[blue] circle[radius=0.08cm];}}}},
    postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark ={between positions 0 and 0.7 step 0.04 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=0.05cm];}}}}
    ] plot[smooth,hobby] coordinates {(0,0.6) (0.4,1) (1,0.4) (1.6,1.2) (2,1.4) (2.6,0.6) (3.4,1.8) (3.8,1.2) (4.4,1.2)(5,0.8) (5.4,0.4) (6,1) (6.6,2) (7,1.6) (7.4,1) (8.2,0.6) (9,0.4)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are some news concerning the `dimension too large` issue. It turns out that a lot of the problems come from the built-in way pgf computes inverses. This issue came up [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529159/194703), and interestingly the same fix that solved the problem there also cures the problem of the decorations here. All it really does is to change the reciprocal to a `fpu` version. The corresponding pgf key `use fpu reciprocal` can be used locally.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,fpu}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529159/194703
\makeatletter
\tikzset{use fpu reciprocal/.code={%
\def\pgfmathreciprocal@##1{%
    \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
    \pgfmathparse{1/##1}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
    \endgroup
}}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use fpu reciprocal]
\draw[postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark ={between positions 0 and 0.7
step 0.04 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=0.05cm];}}}},
postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, 
mark ={between positions 0.6 and 1 step 0.04 with 
{\fill[blue] circle[radius=0.08cm];}}}}] 
plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,0.6) (0.4,1) (1,0.4) (1.6,1.2) (2,1.4) (2.6,0.6) (3.4,1.8) (3.8,1.2) (4.4,1.2)(5,0.8) (5.4,0.4) (6,1) (6.6,2) (7,1.6) (7.4,1) (8.2,0.6) (9,0.4)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]