# "Dimension too large" in this picture, why?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I run the following code, there is a "dimension too large" error:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{24,127,127}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \path[yshift=10,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step .01cm with {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(divide(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength),100)};
                \pgfsetfillcolor{col2!\myval!col1};
                \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{1.5};
                \pgfusepath{fill};}
    }}] 
    ([closed].075,.2)..(.2,.4)..(.8,0)..(.925,.2)..(.8,.4)..(.2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I did a little search on this problem, and it turns out it is neither caused by *length>16384pt* nor incorrect *shift*. The error sometimes disappear when the order of the points at last line changes, but I don't remember the exact order, and I think it is not very relevant to this problem.

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem. [Somewhere on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540276) it has already been pointed out that a large fraction of these errors can be avoided by using a reciprocal from the `fpu` library. This fixes the problem also in your case. Per request by Henri Menke here is a version that works with the newest pgf version, v3.1.6. You can read about this in section **50.2 Handling “Dimension too large” errors** of pgfmanual v3.1.6.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{24,127,127}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,/pgf/fpu/install only={reciprocal}]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \path[yshift=10,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step .01cm with {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(divide(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength),100)};
                \pgfsetfillcolor{col2!\myval!col1};
                \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{1.5};
                \pgfusepath{fill};}
    }}] 
    ([closed].075,.2)..(.2,.4)..(.8,0)..(.925,.2)..(.8,.4)..(.2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you have an older TeX installation use [the original code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529159/227987) that appeared here before this was added to pgf.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{use fpu reciprocal/.code={%
\def\pgfmathreciprocal@##1{%
    \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
    \pgfmathparse{1/##1}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
    \endgroup
}}}%
\makeatother

\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{24,127,127}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{240,240,240}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,use fpu reciprocal]
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \path[yshift=10,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions 0 and \pgfdecoratedpathlength step .01cm with {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{multiply(divide(
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/distance from start}, \pgfdecoratedpathlength),100)};
                \pgfsetfillcolor{col2!\myval!col1};
                \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{1.5};
                \pgfusepath{fill};}
    }}] 
    ([closed].075,.2)..(.2,.4)..(.8,0)..(.925,.2)..(.8,.4)..(.2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `/pgf/fpu/install only={reciprocal}` instead of `use fpu reciprocal`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Done. But now it complains "Package PGF Math Warning: The key `/pgf/fpu/install only' is experimental and m
ight change or disappear at any point! on input line 12.".

Comment: Also it appears that the linked post was one of the first to point out that these errors can be avoided by using the reciprocal from `fpu`.

Comment: @anonymous There are still 12 "dimension too large" error, and there's also `Package pgfkeys: Choice 'orthogonal' unknown in choice key '/pgf/fpu'. I am going to ignore this key.`

Comment: @Jinwen It seems that you are using an older version of pgf. I therefore added a version that works for older version. In fact, this was the code I had posted originally. Only [per request by Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569052/dimension-too-large-in-this-picture-why/569059#comment1434341_569059) I had changed it. Now there are both versions, and hopefully everyone is happy...